# loop through div's with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-slider

I am trying to make a jQuery slider but with div's:

```
<div id="block-1">
        <div id="bannerleft">
            <div class="wsite-header-1"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="bannerright">
            <h2><span class='wsite-text'>CALL US NOW!</span></h2>
            <p><span class='wsite-text'>Call now and get&nbsp;professional service delivered to you by our team of professional plumbers and technicians.<br/><br/>24/7 Emergency Service available</span></p>
            <div style="text-align:left;"><div style="height: 0px; overflow: hidden;"></div>
<a class="wsite-button wsite-button-large wsite-button-highlight" href="contact-us" >
<span class="wsite-button-inner">CALL NOW 1</span>
</a>
<div style="height: 0px; overflow: hidden;"></div></div>
        </div>
        </div>

<div id="block-2" style="display:none;">
        <div id="bannerleft">
            <div class="wsite-header2"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="bannerright">
            <h2><span class='wsite-text'>CALL US NOW! 2</span></h2>
            <p><span class='wsite-text'>Call now and get&nbsp;professional service delivered to you by our team of professional plumbers and technicians.<br/><br/>24/7 Emergency Service available</span></p>
            <div style="text-align:left;"><div style="height: 0px; overflow: hidden;"></div>
<a class="wsite-button wsite-button-large wsite-button-highlight" href="contact-us" >
<span class="wsite-button-inner">CALL NOW 2</span>
</a>
<div style="height: 0px; overflow: hidden;"></div></div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

And here is the jQuery part

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     function animate(){
         $('#block-1').toggle().delay(3000);    
         $('#block-2').toggle().delay(3000); 
         $('#block-3').toggle().delay(3000);         
     } animate();  
     setInterval(animate, 10000);  

});
```

Sadly it doesn't work. It goes to block-2 right away and when it displays block-1 it also shows block-3 under it. Any way how to fix this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I created a demo that fades nicely your elements.
Just added a class `.fade` to all your main DIVs, and a CSS `position:absolute;` to make them overlay properly one over the other.

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/aqukek/2/edit)*

This one will also allow you to pause the slides on hover!

```
var S = 0,             // START 'SLIDE'
    $el = $(".fade"),  // FADE ELEMENTS
    Tim;               // TIMEOUT VAR

function anim(){
  $el.eq(S=++S%$el.length).fadeTo(500,1).siblings($el).stop(1).fadeTo(500,0);
}

function autoAnim(){
    Tim = setTimeout(function(){
      anim();
      autoAnim();
    },4000);
}
autoAnim();

$el.on('mouseenter mouseleave',function(e){
   var m = e.type==='mouseenter' ? clearTimeout( Tim ) : autoAnim();    
}).eq(S).show().siblings($el).hide();
```

HTML:

```
<div id="block-1" class="fade"></div>
<div id="block-2" class="fade"></div>
<div id="block-3" class="fade"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.fade{
  position:absolute;
}
```

Just borrowed the code from a plugin of mine, i you're interested you can [take a look](http://roxon.in/scripts/fademe_jquery_plugin/)
Or if you have Q about the above, feel free to ask

Answer (score 1):

If you want them shown one after another, you can chain them like this:

```
function animate(){
     $('#block-1').toggle(3000, function() {
            $('#block-2').toggle(3000, function() {
                $('#block-3').toggle(3000);
            });
     });     
 } animate();  
 setInterval(animate, 10000);
```

See working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/Gq8Wk/)

Comment: @Cl' Yes my previous version had an error, I think I fixed it in the new code in my updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

Well the hell with it I will just use a working Mootools code I had for ages